# Matching tasks in org-agenda by effort

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock

I have several tasks in an org file, some of which which have an `Effort` property and some of which which don't.

```
** Example Task 1, with effort
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort: 1:30
   :END:
** Example Task 2, without effort
   :PROPERTIES:
   :END:
```

When I run a match query in the agenda (`C-c a m`) and want to check by effort, [this tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) suggests the following. Suppose I want to match all todo tasks whose efforts are estimated to be less than 2 hours. I would do:

```
Match: +Effort<2/TODO
```

However, this also displays todo items which do *not* have an Effort property. (Example Task 2 would be shown along with Example Task 1.)

How can I make it so that having no Effort property results in not appearing in an Effort query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition `EFFORT>0` to the search.

For example if the current `org-mode` buffer contains

```
** Example Task 1, with effort
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort: 1:30
   :END:

** Example Task 2, without effort
   :PROPERTIES:
   :END:

** Example Task 3, with effort
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort: 3:00
   :END:
```

Then `C-c a < m EFFORT>0+EFFORT<2` (the first `<` is to just restrict the search to the current buffer) returns

```
Headlines with TAGS match: EFFORT>0+EFFORT<2
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again with new search string
  b:          Example Task 1, with effort
```

If you wish to search on efforts of the form `0:15` etc. then you should enclose all values in double quotes, e.g.

```
C-c a < m EFFORT>"0"+EFFORT<"0:30"
```

Comment: Hmm... this seems to work for whole number efforts... but is there a way to search for fractional ones (like 0:15, 0:30, 0:45)? If I search for `EFFORT>0+EFFORT<1`, I get no results.

Comment: @wiuah Just add quotes - I have added a final example to demonstrate this.